# Counter(dict1)+Counter(dict2) gives the wrong answer

Tags: python

```
from Q import *
from collections import Counter

#Q1, Q2 are dictionaries which are imported from Q.py
Q1 = Counter(Q1)
Q2 = Counter(Q2)
Q = Q1+Q2

ene = 0.0
for k,v in Q1.items():
    ene += v
print(ene)

ene = 0.0
for k,v in Q2.items():
    ene += v
print(ene)

ene = 0.0
for k,v in Q.items():
    ene += v
print(ene)
```

Then run the code, I got the output:

```
-6.81022233745
0.0
39542.4622651
```

Why does not the last line equal the sum of the previous 2 lines?
Plz help! Thank you.

Comment: Please edit this to include a [mcve]. Show us some data for `Q1` and `Q2`, and write the expected output too.

Comment: I don’t think `Counter` is supposed to be used for things that aren’t integers. The [current documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) says “Counts are allowed to be any integer value including zero or negative counts.” There’s a note later on covering looser restrictions on some operations, but I definitely wouldn’t use it for floats regardless.

Comment: Could you add a little more info to explain what your code is meant to do? count(dict1) + count(dict2) is a bit too simple to understand the code's purpose

Comment: `import *` is considered bad style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

> The multiset methods are designed only for use cases with positive values. The inputs may be negative or zero, but only outputs with positive values are created. There are no type restrictions, but the value type needs to support addition, subtraction, and comparison.

The `+` operator counts as a multiset method – no need to even involve floats:

```
>>> Counter() + Counter({'a': -5})
Counter()
```

An alternative could be a `defaultdict(float)`:

```
from Q import Q1, Q2
from collections import defaultdict

Q = defaultdict(float, Q1)

for k, v in Q2.items():
    Q[k] += v
```